# Compile ASP.NET to 64 BIT

Tags: asp.net

My development machine is Win XP Pro 32 bit and production machine is Windows Server 2008 (64 Bit) with IIS 7. On my development machine I want to compile ASP.NET (Using aspnet compiler) to 64 bit byte code.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that? Please do not suggest any way to run 32 bit application on 64 bit environment.

I want 64 bit application to be compiled on 32 bit machine so that when it runs it will take full advantage of 64 bit O/S without any emulation.

Answer (score 25):

Leave the target platform at AnyCpu and .NET will automatically run natively on 64bit when executed on a 64Bit operating system

Clarification:

(this started out as a comment but I thought it might be interesting for the question as well)

Actually you never compile to a special architecture. You always compile to IL.

That's something like Java Bytecode. And that bytecode is the same for 32 bit and 64 bit.

The Virtual Machine (.NET Framework) on the machine the code gets executed then compiles the IL to actual machine code while running (through the Just In Time compilation). So, no matter where you compile, you'll always end up in IL that's bit-ignorant.

The setting in .NET is only an instruction in IL that tells the JIT (Just in Time compiler) to specifically use 32bit/64 bit. By flipping that one bit in your assembly you could still execute it in AnyCpu or x64 without recompilation.

This setting is only used and needed in case you call out to native code that isn't bit-ignorant (when interacting with COM components or doing p/invoke calls)

Comment: I am compiling ASP.NET (File system mode and not web application project) through aspnet_compiler (Only .NET 2.0 32 bit is installed and hence using 32 bit framework). What I understood is that if I copy all the dlls which are under \bin to my production machine it will fully run in 64 bit mode without any emulation. I just wanted to confirm that there should not be any performance issue when application is compiled on 32 bit machine and ran on 64 bit. Since I do not have web application project then in that case will aspnet_compiler compile to AnyCPU mode??. 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18):

There's an option in Visual Studio 2013 now to direct IIS Express (which is usually used for debug) to run in 64 bit mode.

It's at `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express…`

Comment: This answer solved my problem today. Go to up vote, and realize it's my own answer from two years ago, FTW!

Comment: There is also a project-specific setting for this so you don't have to override the entire IDE defaults (and depend on other people setting them). `Project Properties -> Web -> Servers section -> Bitness: x64`. You can choose to save this to the project file so everyone has the same settings. (this is in VS2017, not sure about other versions having it)

Answer (score 6):

.net apps will re-target themselves for the target machine environment assuming that you didn't specifically choose to compile in 32-bit mode.  This can be found under the project build options.

Comment: Correct, just be sure you're not optimizing for a specific architecture and you should be all set.