# Can I deploy SharePoint solutions with 32 bit assemblies on a 64 bit SharePoint farm?

Tags: sharepoint, 64-bit, 32-bit

Our development environment is all 32 bit, but our production SharePoint farms are all 64 bit.  Can we just deploy the SharePoint solutions straight to the 64 bit platform, or do we need to recompile everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Platform Target set to "Any CPU" (which is the default) then you do not need to recompile. You can find this drop-down by going to the Build tab in the project properties. The .NET Framework is smart enough to adjust to either platform when this setting is enabled.

I'm working in the same environment that you describe with these settings and have no issues.

**Edit:** A good question that describes this further - [Compile ASP.NET to 64 BIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040165/compile-asp-net-to-64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly offtopic, but if you deliver your solution files through MSI's build as a simple Visual Studio Setup Project, like we do, that's a different story. Those MSI's *are* 32 bits, and require a [fair bit of modding](http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2005/10/24/windows-installer-on-64-bit-platforms.aspx) to make them 64 bits compatible.

The solutions themselves, however, should pose no problem whatsoever.

Comment: MSIs and SharePoint is not a good mix in my opinion! Try and have a look at http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller for a dedicated SharePoint Solution installer.

Comment: A reason MSIs are not good with SharePoint is because MSIs are machine-based.  You install/uninstall on a machine.  However, SharePoint solutions are farm-based and can affect multiple machines in the farm.

Comment: MSI's and solutions have separate roles. We deliver the MSI to install the Solution in the first place (our consultants prefer not to have to touch the command line unless unexpected things happens during installation), then deploy the solution to whatever machines they want.