# How comes my C++ assembly is seen from a C# console application but not an ASP.NET one?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dllimport

I wrote a C++ dll. It has one function, which returns the double 1.0.

I attempted to use it in a C# console application:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{

    class Program
        {
        [DllImport(@"C:\path\to\my\dll\myDll.dll")]
        static extern double SendOne();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double i = SendOne();
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This works.

I then attempted to use it in an ASP.NET application, created with an empty MVC application, and then adding one controller and one view :

Controllers/HomeController.cs:

```
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\path\to\my\dll\myDll.dll")]
        static extern double SendOne();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            double i = SendOne();
            ViewBag["result"] = i;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        This is some text and the result : @{ ViewBag["result"]}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work, and returns a BadImageFormatException.

In all three projects, I manually configured the Platform to be **Debug / x64** (from the default Debug / AnyCPU).

This is the bottom of the stack trace : (First line manually translated from french)

```
[BadImageFormatException: Impossible charge the file or assembly '[Name of the ASP.NET Project]' or one of its dependencies. Attempt to load a program of incorrect format.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
```

Top of the stack trace : HttpException 0x80004005.

Both the ASP.NET Project & the C# Console App are two projects in the same Visual Studio 2017 Solution, that do not reference each other and that I launch separately.

I don't get the differences that exist between an ASP.NET project and a C# Console App that could cause the Native C++ Dll loading to work in the C# Console App and fail in the ASP.NET project.

Would anyone know the issue or have advices on what I can try ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidHeffernan's answer, my research led me to this question : [Compile ASP.NET to 64 BIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040165/compile-asp-net-to-64-bit)

Which had in alternative answers what would solve my problem : regardless of whether the ASP.NET is compiled as 32 bits or 64 bits, the *debugger*, IIS Express, runs in 32 bits, which conflicts with using a 64 bits C++ dll.

It is necessary to change the version of the debugger, this can be done at `Visual Studio -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bits version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`.

Comment: That's the answer I gave you isn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't find what "buffered bitness" means, so I assumed it meant different bitness, but I was compiling the ASP.NET version as 64 bits from the start, as stated in my answer. Here I'm stating that even though I did compile ASP.NET as 64 bits, the debugger is by default 32 bits, even in 64 bits compilation mode ! And how to fix it.

Comment: You seem to be confused between the answer to your question and the solution to your problem.

Comment: My question was "What's the issue", so saying that it's bitness-related isn't as precise as saying it comes from the bitness of the debugger. You did lead me to the solution by giving me the nature of the problem, but I thought I would give a more complete answer for future users.

Comment: Never mind. I don't think you understand how this site works. Your answer refers to all sorts of details not present in the question. Specific to you. I think I answered the question that was asked, and I'm sorry that you don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

`BadImageFormatException` is raised when the program attempts to load a module with mismatching bitness. Hat is, 64 but process tries to load 32 bit module or vice versa. So it seems that the ASP process is a buffered bitness from the console app.

Comment: I am quite certain the console app is 64 bits, as I could successfully use in the dll functions from a library that I believe only runs in 64 bits environments.

This would mean the ASP.NET process is somehow 32 bits, despite me compiling the project with x64. How comes ? The accurate traceback of my ASP.NET project creation is ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) > add the controller and the view > Configuration Manager > Platform > <New...> > x64 / Debug. Ticking create new solution platform doesn't seem to matter.

I could record my minimalistic project creation if it helps.